# Videos not playing

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, google-chrome, video, virtualization

I recently installed Ubuntu in a VM on Windows 10 and have the problem that videos just don't want to play. Youtube and other websites don't work. Not even downloading the videos and playing them with the default player doesn't work. Installing VLC fixed the problem with downloaded videos but videos in Firefox / Chrome still don't work. I have another Ubuntu VM (which I currently can't access because it's encrypted) where everything seems to work just fine. There's no error or anything popping up when I try to watch a video just the first frame in a static picture.

Things I tried that didn't fix the problem:

- Rebooting
- Using the command`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras` to install codecs
- Rebooting after that
- Installing Chrome
- Rebooting again
- Updating all software
- And again rebooting

The only solution I can find is to install the restricted extras which doesn't fix the problem for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't say what kind of Virtualization Software you use.  Tools like VMWare Workstation and VirtualBox have so called "Guest Tools".  Basically, some kind of drivers for the virtual machine, so it interacts better with the host machine (your Windows 10).  I'd suggest that you start off looking whether such a thing exists for your virtualization solution.

Comment: Hello first off thanks for the answer! I added it in the tags but totally forgot to mention that I'm using virtualbox. The Guest Tools are already installed so that's not it either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution for this a few weeks ago somewhere and it worked for me. I realized the videos don't play on the VM because of the audio settings (and not any video settings).

1. Shut down the VM (in my case Ubuntu 16.04.1).
2. In VirtualBox, click "Settings".
3. Go to the "Audio" section and change the "Audio Controller" from the default to the other available option ("Intel HD Audio" controller was my 2nd option).
4. Start the Virtual Machine and see if this work.

Comment: Yea this was it, found the solution trough trial and error too. Forgot to update the post though thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling 3D acceleration in the VM display settings fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but in case someone else stumbles across this.  I already had the above proposed solutions set on my system.  What resolved this for me was going into the VirtualBox VM settings > Network > Advanced and change the Adapter Type to "Paravirtualized Network (virtio-net)."  So maybe it's a combination of some/all of these suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This was so annoying for me as the video would load and buffer but not play.

- Virtualbox Version 6.0.12 r133076 (Qt5.6.2)
- Ubuntu version 19 Dancing Dingo.
- Audio ICH AC97 (default)
- Video no acceleration (default)

Default audio settings:

[image]

Default display settings:

[image]

I tried the above advice:

- Audio setting changed to HD Audio

This did not fix playback stuck problem.

Then I tried the above advice above

- Video 3D Acceleration was changed to check / enable

This did fix playback stuck problem. Then I reverted the settings to prove it was the proper fix, and for a while it did work without the changes.  Then it stopped working again.  So there are some side-effects happening.

In the end, it seems the changes are required for Ubuntu 19 but not Ubuntu 18.

Thankfully it is now working for Ubuntu 19, Disco Dingo.

Comment: The screenshots are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well and the best solution I could come up with is changing the browser, I think this issue is more relevant with firefox users, so if you install chromium or another browser you could compare to see if the issue is with settings or browser issues, hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed changing the Graphics controller to VMSVGA even if it was flagged as not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If None of the above works simply do the following steps it.

```
1. GO to preference/setting by pressing 'Right CTRL + S'
2. Navigate to Audio.
3. Uncheck the Enable audio box.
```

You will not get the audio but Video will work for sure